# Optimizing vector size for too many values

Tags: c++, iteration, stdvector

I have the following code:

```
vector<Foo> objects(num_values);


for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

    objects[i].m = 15;
    cout << particles[i].m<< endl;
}
```

With struct:

```
struct Foo {
    int m;
};
```

What I'm doing here is iterating 15 for int m of a class Foo (and printing it for visibility). At the end of this loop, I should have a vector of size num_objects, with m=15 for every point in the array.

This code works, only the problem is that num_values is greater than max_size(), representing a value of roughly 10^25. Running this gives me the error:

**Unhandled exception at 0x7682B522 in example.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x005CF4EC.**

I could reduce the frame of reference of my program as to reduce the array size, but I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize it instead so this fits.

Comment: Um, how much ram do you have?

Comment: Assuming you're running on a 64-bit CPU where `sizeof(size_t)==8`, the largest number of items you could conceivably fit into a `std::vector` (given sufficient RAM) would be `2^64-1`, aka `18446744073709551615` items.  `10^25` items is much more than that.

Comment: For all practical purposes, `10^25 == infinity` :)

Comment: Assume for the moment you could do this. If it takes you one _femtosecond_ to perform this initialization (or, to do whatever you'll do iterating over this vector) then you're looking at about 317 years to complete it. You'll need a different approach.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? We can't suggest optimizations if we don't know the goal. Either way, you're not making a vector that size.

Comment: All very good points. For reference, I was looking if there was a way to initialize a realistic amount of particles in a fluid for a simulation I'm trying to execute. I will need to develop some other algorithm to greatly reduce this amount while maintaining accuracy.

Comment: and 10^25 isn't much more than a mole of liquid.. I suppose, whole task requires reformulation

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie nobody simulates liquids on quark level for a very good yet simple reason. Also not sure what it has to do with this, but even if you encoded every entity into a single bit somehow, 10^25 bits is still 1 250 000 000 000 terabytes and if you can afford this much RAM, let alone build computer that can make use of it, you probably aren't asking questions like "why can't my workstation with 32GB RAM allocate and index yottabytes of data?".

Comment: @Sahsahae I worked for 10 year in organization where bosses believed that they don't need programmers and CS to write programs, they just need mathematicians and engineers (non_IT ones). Those  they were taking as employees were clueless about  computer capabilities, how concurrency work, concept of UB, etc. But actually is going here, as I suspect is some FEM simulation with very sparse system of elements  attempted to be solved in "math textbook" way. I saw that before. Textbook way essentially defines a matrix. It grows incredibly fast, because rank of matrix is equal to number of vertices.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I don't know enough about math to say anything about this, but what I do know is that yes, concepts like infinity work just fine in math. Sadly in reality there's no such thing and we are bounded by unknown, and even more often, by our own incompetence, so we set limits for what we do know, and work from there. Sparse matrix with no real bound sounds like a disaster on any system that does something important. Hence what FEM stands for after all... Finite Element Method. Also no, that still does not work, the moment you observe something and even modify, it has to be in memory